# Не могу найти класс, в котором определён метод setButtonText для QMessageBox (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Приветстсвую! Никак не могу найти в документации, кто определяет метод класса `setButtonText`. Вызывается он из объекта класса `QMessageBox`. Однако в документации нет информации про этот метод. Вот код:

```
 QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Question,
                    tr("Sure want to quit?"),
                    tr("Sure to quit?"),
                    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
                    this);
            messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("Да"));
            messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("Нет"));
            messageBox.exec();
       }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, чей метод `setButtonText` и почему объекты класса `QMessageBox` имеют к нему доступ?

Comment: Значит нужно смотреть в классах от которых `QMessageBox` наследуется. Это же ООП

Comment: Это устаревший член  класса QMessageBox, поэтому в ее не можете найти  ее в интерфейсе и в документации, но можете найти искав в разделе устаревших членов. Вместо нее используйте метод addButton.